# Сравнить две коробки. Что не так?

Tags: java

На столе две коробки.

Первый блок имеет размер `X1 x Y1 x Z1`, а второй блок имеет размер `X2 x Y2 x Z2`.

Вам необходимо определить, какую коробку можно поместить в другую коробку. Вы можете вращать оба поля, как вы хотите.

Вход содержит две строки. Первая строка содержит числа `X1, Y1, Z1`, вторая строка содержит числа `X2, Y2, Z2`. Все числа целые числа и больше 0.

- Если размеры блоков равны, выведите `«Box 1 = Box 2»`.
- Если первый блок можно поместить во второй блок, выведите `«Box 1 <Box 2»`.
- Если второй блок можно поместить в первый блок, выведите `«Box 1> Box 2»`.
- Если ни один из блоков не может быть помещен в другой блок, выведите `«Incomparable»`.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        int b = scanner.nextInt();
        int c = scanner.nextInt();
        int a1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int b1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int c1 = scanner.nextInt();

        if (((a + b + c) == (a1 + b1 + c1)) & ((a == a1 | a == b1 | 
              a == c1) & (b == a1 | b == b1 | b == c1) & (c == a1 | 
              c == b1 | c == c1))) {
             System.out.println("Box 1 = Box 2");
        } else if (((a + b + c) < (a1 + b1 + c1)) & ((a < a1 | a < 
              b1 | a < c1) & (b < a1 | b < b1 | b < c1) & (c < a1 | 
              c < b1 | c < c1))) {
             System.out.println("Box 1 < Box 2");
        } else if (((a + b + c) > (a1 + b1 + c1)) & ((a > a1 | a > 
              b1 | a > c1) & (b > a1 | b > b1 | b > c1) & (c > a1 | 
              c > b1 | c > c1))) {
             System.out.println("Box 1 > Box 2");
        } else if ((a > a1 | a >= b1 | a >= c1) & (b > a1 | b >= b1 
              | b >= c1) & (c > a1 | c >= b1 | c >= c1)) {
             System.out.println("Incomparable");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Все не так, ребята.* Зачем суммы?

Упорядочите тройки чисел по возрастанию. А потом сравнивайте поэлементно.

*Одна коробка помещается в другую, если каждый элемент из упорядоченного списка размеров первой коробки (строго?) меньше соответствующего элемента из упорядоченного списка размеров второй коробки.*

P.S. И нет никакой необходимости использовать полное вычисление булевских выражений.

---

> Прошло такое решение. Что в нем можно улучшить?

```
Arrays.sort(arr1); 
Arrays.sort(arr2);
int eq = 0, ge = 0, le = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  eq = eq + (arr1[i] == arr2[i]? 1 : -1);
  ge = ge + (arr1[i] >= arr2[i]? 1 : -1);
  le = le + (arr1[i] <= arr2[i]? 1 : -1);
}
if (eq == arr1.length) {
  System.out.println("Box 1 = Box 2"); 
} else if (ge == arr1.length) {
  System.out.println("Box 1 > Box 2"); 
} else if (le == arr1.length) {
  System.out.println("Box 1 < Box 2"); 
} else {
  System.out.println("Incomparable"); 
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо. Прошло такое решение. Что в нем можно улучшить?
// сканер массивов//
        Arrays.sort(arr1);
        Arrays.sort(arr2);
        if (arr1[0] == arr2[0] & arr1[2] == arr2[2] & arr1[1] == arr2[1]) {
            System.out.println("Box 1 = Box 2");
        } else if (arr1[0] >= arr2[0] & arr1[1] >= arr2[1] & arr1[2] >= arr2[2]) {
            System.out.println("Box 1 > Box 2");
        } else if (arr1[0] <= arr2[0] & arr1[1] <= arr2[1] & arr1[2] <= arr2[2]) {
            System.out.println("Box 1 < Box 2");
        } else System.out.println("Incomparable");

    }
}