# Как сравнить размеры двух ящиков?

Tags: php, c++, python, алгоритм, любой-язык

Даны два ящика с размерами (L,B,H). Нужно написать красивую(оптимизация по скорости) функцию сравнения размеров, `function sizes_compare(l1, b1, h1, l2, b2, h2):booleean`, на выходе: равны/не равны. Учитывая, что ящики (1,2,3), (1,3,2), (2,1,3), (2,3,1), (3,1,2) и (3,2,1) являются одинаковыми(просто перевёрнуты в пространстве).

Что-то у меня всё ну очень получается длинно. Хеш функцию придумать не получилось, проскакивают коллизии. Прямым сравниванием получается шпагетти-код. Если представить как два массива, отсортировать и сравнить, как-то уж слишком замудрённо...

язык не важен, интересны идеи как это можно оптимально реализовать. Используется в критическом месте, нужна оптимизация по скорости исполнения.

Comment: Сравнить отсотированные триплеты?

Comment: я это описал уже в вопросе, оно работает стабильно, без промахов, но это максимально не оптимальный код в итоге же

Comment: *>Если представить как два массива, отсортировать и сравнить, как-то уж слишком замудрённо...* - почему же замудрённо? Отсортировать 2 массива по 3 элемента каждый и покомпонентно сравнить. На мой взгляд, самое оптимальное решение.

Comment: т.е. математически никак не получится? Если числа всегда целые и в пределах от 1 до 7 например?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1049768/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba/1049772#1049772

Comment: Мне кажется, что предложение отсортировать и сравнить как раз правильное

Comment: Все со всевозможными целыми размерами сторон от 1 до 7

Comment: ТС намекает на возможное существование решения, основанного на некой битовой магии :)

Comment: Я начинаю склоняться к тому, что таки прямыми сравнениями, которых будет в худшем случае 18 штук (3!=6 вариантов по 3 значения), по скорости получается самый оптимальный вариант.

Comment: @Isaev, неверно, сортировка трех элементов выполняется за 3 сравнения, итого 3+3+3=9

Comment: Да и без сортировки, если сравнивать не всё сразу, а по одному числу и размести по веткам, то наверное меньше 18 сравнений будет, но читаться это будет вообще плохо. Поэтому я за вариант с сортировкой, берем метод `Regularize` [отсюда](https://github.com/AndrewNowosad/AreaCalculator/blob/509e4106b3284ca741c7b30ad194f0e942e624ee/AreaCalculator/TriangleAreaCalculator.cs#L38) и пишем `Regularize(ref l1, ref b1, ref h1); Regularize(ref l2, ref b2, ref h2); return l1 == l2 && b1 == b2 && h1 == h2;` Получаем 3 коротеньких метода по 1-3 строк

Comment: сортировка это, к сожалению не только сравнения, то и перемещения в памяти, что всегда более медленно. И это отдельно для обоих массивов, а потом ещё и сравнения. Читаться будет очень плохо, согласен, но надо по скорости оптимизировать

Comment: @Isaev, конечно, надо смотреть, но с большой вероятностью программа сортировки 3-х чисел после оптимизации компилятором будет выполнять все промежуточные действия над данными в регистрах (по крайней мере в x86-64 и Aarch64)

Answer (score 5):

Отсортировать и сравнить последовательно - самый нормальный вариант.

При этом сортировать можно как сортировкой массива, так и просто руками.

https://ideone.com/d9i6xm

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a[3], b[3];

  scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", a, a+1, a+2, b, b+1, b+2);

  sort(a, a+3);
  sort(b, b+3);

  puts(a[0]==b[0] && a[1]==b[1] && a[2]==b[2] ? "YES" : "NO");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "самый нормальный вариант." возможно... сейчас так и работает, хотелось бы ускориться

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как быстро отсортировать 3 элемента?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/789961/218063)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да, можно так. Хотя тут рядом уже [запостили](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1069555/178988). А вот за что минусы обоим ответам, я не понимаю ((

Answer (score 3):

В общем на основе ответов вырисовалось 3 основные концепта, решил реализовать все 3 поиска и сравнить по производительности:

**1. Сравнение прямыми проверками:**

```
function sizes_comapre(a, b: TSize): Boolean;
begin
  Result := false;
  if a.x <> b.x then begin
    if a.x <> b.y then begin
      if a.x <> b.z then begin
        exit;
      end else begin
        {$REGION '[1,x,x][x,x,1]'}
        if a.y <> b.x then begin
          if a.y <> b.y then begin
            exit;
          end else begin
            //[1,2,x][x,2,1]
            if a.z <> b.x then begin
              exit;
            end else begin
              //[1,2,3][3,2,1]
              exit(true);
            end;
          end;
        end else begin
          //[1,2,x][2,x,1]
          if a.z <> b.y then begin
            exit;
          end else begin
            //[1,2,3][2,3,1]
            exit(true);
          end;
        end;
        {$ENDREGION}
      end;
    end else begin
      {$REGION '[1,x,x][x,1,x]'}
      if a.y <> b.x then begin
        if a.y <> b.z then begin
          exit;
        end else begin
          //[1,2,x][x,1,2]
          if a.z <> b.x then begin
            exit;
          end else begin
            //[1,2,3][3,1,2]
            exit(true);
          end;
        end;
      end else begin
        //[1,2,x][2,1,x]
        if a.z <> b.z then begin
          exit;
        end else begin
          //[1,2,3][2,1,3]
          exit(true);
        end;
      end;
      {$ENDREGION}
    end;
  end else begin
    {$REGION '[1,x,x][1,x,x]'}
    if a.y <> b.y then begin
      if a.y <> b.z then begin
        exit;
      end else begin
        //[1,2,x][1,x,2]
        if a.z <> b.y then begin
          exit;
        end else begin
          //[1,2,3][1,3,2]
          exit(true);
        end;
      end;
    end else begin
      //[1,2,x][1,2,x]
      if a.z <> b.z then begin
        exit;
      end else begin
        //[1,2,3][1,2,3]
        exit(true);
      end;
    end;
    {$ENDREGION}
  end;
end;
```

**2. Сравнение математически (на основе теоремы Виета):**

```
function sizes_comapre2(a, b: TSize): Boolean;
begin
  Result := false;
  if a.x + a.y + a.z <> b.x + b.y + b.z then
    exit;
  if a.x * a.y * a.z <> b.x * b.y * b.z then
    exit;
  //LB+LH+BH
  Result := (a.x * a.y + a.x * a.z + a.y * a.z = b.x * b.y + b.x * b.z + b.y * b.z);
end;
```

**3. Сравнение сортировкой двух триплетов и последующим последовательным сравнением:**

```
function sizes_comapre3(a, b: TSize): Boolean;
var
  temp: Byte;
begin
  {$REGION 'Sort a'}
  if a.z < a.y then begin
    temp := a.y;
    a.y := a.z;
    a.z := temp;
  end;
  if a.z < a.x then begin
    temp := a.x;
    a.x := a.z;
    a.z := temp;
  end;
  if a.y < a.x then begin
    temp := a.y;
    a.y := a.x;
    a.x := temp;
  end;
  {$ENDREGION}
  {$REGION 'Sort b'}
  if b.z < b.y then begin
    temp := b.y;
    b.y := b.z;
    b.z := temp;
  end;
  if b.z < b.x then begin
    temp := b.x;
    b.x := b.z;
    b.z := temp;
  end;
  if b.y < b.x then begin
    temp := b.y;
    b.y := b.x;
    b.x := temp;
  end;
  {$ENDREGION}
  Result := ((a.x = b.x) and (a.y = b.y) and (a.z = b.z));
end;
```

**Результаты для 10 Млн проверок:**

```
Time[sort1]: 0,2930 sek
Time[sort2]: 0,2896 sek
Time[sort3]: 0,5455 sek
Time[empty pass]: 0,2207 sek
```

Как и предполагалось, предварительная сортировка с последующим сравненим [3] оказалась самой долгой.

Удивило, что математический подход [2] оказался, хоть и немного, но быстрее прямой проверки [1], хотя там довольно много умножений... При чём при значениях 1..7 последней, самой сложной проверкой можно пренебречь, она нужна только для значений >= 8.

В общем буду использовать его, к тому же он и в реализации самый простой и наиболее наглядный.

Comment: ничего неожиданного) при "прямой" проверке очень много условных переходов. От которых компилятор даже не факт что избавится. Можно попробовать кстати какую-нибудь ДНФ сделать или подобное на 9 переменных сравнения. Но не уверен что будет быстрее.

Comment: Сортировка и сравнение на ассемблере (Win64) показывает такую же скорость, как  sizes_comapre2. Но неужели 10 нс (30 тактов) на сравнение является в этой задаче лимитирующим фактором?

Comment: @MBo, спасибо за асм тест! Может именно в данном случае и не является, я не думал, что на столько различные подходы дадут на столько близкие результаты. Но из нс складываются минуты и часы и  в итоге, когда программа вместо 16 часов отрабатывает за 10, это приятно.

Comment: А подход нельзя изменить, чтобы столько проверок не пришлось  делать?

Comment: @MBo, она строит граф, размер которого ограничен лишь объёмом оперативки, в котором потом ищет решения. Поиск решения потом занимает доли секунды, а вот построение самого графа довольно временнозатратно (в районе 300млн узлов хватает доступных 92гб мне сейчас), т.к. для добавления следующего узла нужно проверить предыдущие, чтобы исключить дубли. Красно-черные деревья в этом деле очень помогли.

Answer (score 2):

На всякий случай, ручная сортировка массива из 3-х элементов по убыванию

```
#define SWAP(x, i, j) {typeof (*x) *_a = x; typeof (*x) t = _a[i]; _a[i] = _a[j]; _a[j] = t;}

static void inline sort3 (int a[3])
{
  if (a[0] < a[1])
    SWAP(a, 0, 1);
  if (a[0] < a[2])
    SWAP(a, 0, 2);
  if (a[1] < a[2])
    SWAP(a, 1, 2);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Прочитал, можно и тут почистить

Answer (score 2):

Такая проверка делает то что вам надо, по крайней мере если все числа целые от 1 до 7, также она очевидно очень быстра)

```
a1 + b1 + c1 == a2 + b2 + c2 and a1 * b1 * c1 == a2 * b2 * c2
```

Чтобы доказать отсутствие коллизий можно запустить такой скрипт:

```py
from itertools import product

pairs = product(
    product(range(1, 8), range(1, 8), range(1, 8)),
    product(range(1, 8), range(1, 8), range(1, 8))
)

for box1, box2 in pairs:
    if (box1[0] + box1[1] + box1[2] == box2[0] + box2[1] + box2[2]) and (box1[0] * box1[1] * box1[2] == box2[0] * box2[1] * box2[2]):
        assert list(sorted(box1)) == list(sorted(box2))
```

Я понимаю что можно было бы вывести математическое доказательство отсутствия коллизий, но у меня нет идей. Если кто-нибудь это сделает буду благодарен.

Comment: Да, всё правильно, от 1 до 7 её вполне хватает, сделал обзор трёх проверок в своём ответе, там этот вариант тоже есть

Comment: До 7 - вроде да, а вообще - нет. `1 5 8` и `2 2 10`. Среди чисел до 100 есть 6787 групп, содержащих более одного набора. Вот код: ```res = new Map();
for (q=1; q<100; ++q) for (w=q; w<100; ++w) for (e=w; e<100; ++e) s = `${q*w*e} ${q+w+e}`, res.has(s) ? res.get(s).push([q,w,e]) : res.set(s, [[q,w,e]]);
[...res.values()].filter(x => x.length>1);```

Answer (score 0):

Для случая сильно ограниченного набора значений, можно просто подобрать хеш-функцию, так чтобы небыло коллизий. Поскольку мы свертываем 9 бит (3*3=9) в 32, то подходит буквально первый попавшийся хеш:

```
uint32_t circular_hash(uint8_t i)
{
    return  uint32_t(i) ^ uint32_t(12345678u)  ;
}

typedef std::tuple<uint8_t,uint8_t,uint8_t> triple;
uint32_t circular_hash(triple t)
{
    return circular_hash( std::get<0>(t) )
         * circular_hash( std::get<1>(t) )
         * circular_hash( std::get<2>(t) );
}
```

тест:

```
std::map< uint32_t, triple > test;

for( uint8_t a=0; a<=8; ++a  )
    for( uint8_t b=a; b<=8; ++b  )
        for( uint8_t c=b; c<=8; ++c  )
        {
            triple t={a,b,c};
            uint32_t h=circular_hash(t);
            if(test.count(h)!=0)
            {
                triple t2=test[h];
                std::cout<<"error: "<<h<< " : " << t  <<" = " << t2  <<std::endl;
            }
            test[h]=t;
        }
return 0;
```